# Calculating winding number

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

Let
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma= \gamma_1 +\gamma_2+\gamma_3,\\
\gamma_1(t)=e^{it}, t\in[0,2\pi] \\
\gamma_2(t)=-1+2e^{-2it}, t\in [0,2\pi]\\
\gamma_3(t)=1-i+e^{it},t\in [\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{9\pi}{2}]
\end{align}
$$

Calculate the value of $n(\gamma,z)$ as $z$ takes its value in $\mathbb{C}\backslash\gamma.$

$\gamma$ is the image of the closed curve.

as $\gamma$ is a closed and smooth by parts, we have that

$$
n(\gamma,z)= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_\gamma\frac{dc}{c-z} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \left[ \int\limits_{\gamma_1}\frac{dc}{c-z}+ \int\limits_{\gamma_2}\frac{dc}{c-z} + \int\limits_{\gamma_3}\frac{dc}{c-z}\right]
$$

as  $\gamma_1'(t) = ie^{it}$, $\gamma_2'(t) = -4ie^{-2it}$ and $\gamma_3'(t) = ie^{it}$

i can compute those integrals as

$$
n(\gamma,z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \left[ \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{it}dt}{e^{it}-z}+ \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{-4ie^{-2it}dt}{-1+2e^{-2it}-z} + \int\limits_{\pi /2}^{9\pi /2}\frac{ie^{it}}{1-i+e^{it}-z}\right]
$$

but when i compute then for any point i am finding $0$, did i made any mistake or am i making one when computing those integrals?

Comment: That's clear as far as it goes (by the way, a factor of $\frac1{2\pi i}$ has  accidentally become $2\pi i$, in two places), but it would be easier to see what's going wrong if you also explained briefly how you went about calculating one of the integrals, say the first one, for some value of $z$. On the question as a whole: I imagine you are expected to draw a figure, and use it to help you to apply a general result about winding numbers of circles about points, rather than calculating several integrals from first principles, which looks like an excessive amount of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value depends on $z$. Note that $\gamma_1$ runs once counterclockwise around the circle with center $0$ and radius $1$, $\gamma_2$ runs twice clockwise around the circle with center $-1$ and radius $2$, $\gamma_3$ runs twice counterclockwise around the circle with center $1-i$ and radius $1$. Let $D_i$ be the open disk bounded by $\gamma_i$. Note that $D_1 \subset D_2$. Drawing a picture is helpful. For a point $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \gamma$ we get $n(\gamma,z) = n(\gamma_1,z) + n(\gamma_2,z) + n(\gamma_3,z)$. We have $n(\gamma_1,z) = 1$ for $z \in D_1$, $n(\gamma_1,z) = 0$ for $z \notin D_1$, $n(\gamma_2,z) = -2$ for $z \in D_2$, $n(\gamma_2,z) = 0$ for $z \notin D_2$, $n(\gamma_3,z) = 2$ for $z \in D_3$, $n(\gamma_3,z) = 0$ for $z \notin D_3$. Thus:

1. If $z \in D_1 \cap D_3$, then $n(\gamma,z) = 1 -2 + 2 = 1$.
2. If $z \in D_1 \setminus D_3$, then $n(\gamma,z) = 1- 2 + 0 = -1$.
3. If $z \in D_2 \setminus (D_1 \cup D_3)$, then $n(\gamma,z) = 0 -2 + 0 = -2$.
4. If $z \in (D_2 \cap D_3) \setminus D_1 $, then $n(\gamma,z) = 0 -2 + 2 = 0$.
5. If $z \in D_3 \setminus D_2$, then $n(\gamma,z) = 0 + 0 + 2 = 2$.
6. If $z \notin D_1  \cup D_2 \cup D_3$, then $n(\gamma,z) = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0$.